# How else could you tell a person you "are curious about them"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, word-usage

For example, "You induce/promote/inspire curiosity in me." "I am very curious in you." (Sounds awful)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Have you consulted a thesaurus? You'll also have to explain why *I am curious about you* sounds "awful." I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for a better understanding of how this site operates.

Comment: @choster I did and intrigue was not listed anywhere, although I believe that is the term I was looking for.  "I am curious about you." works, I was looking for an alternate form.  "I am curious in you." was what I thought sounds bad.  Can you suggest what I need to change so the post is not on hold?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Intrigue***

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intrigue): to arouse the interest, desire, or curiosity of

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intrigue): to achieve or earn by appealing to another's curiosity, fancy, or interest

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/intrigue): to interest someone a lot, especially by being strange, unusual, or mysterious

[Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/intrigue_1): to make someone very interested in knowing more about something, especially something that seems mysterious

*You intrigue me*

*I am intrigued by you.*